# How do you access main Discord ".js" from seperate command modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I want to make a Discord Bot, and I have a very litte knowledge of Node.js and I was wondering how do I access variables and objects and any data type in the main `index.js` file of the bot from the seperate command module files (the files that have `module.exports={...}`).
I want to be able to access those datas so that whenever i change the value of something in a module it is changed in the main `.js` to access the new information from another module.
Codes aren't really necessary for an answer(but still preferred), I'm looking at this "theoretically"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's say you have code in `index.js` like so:

```js
const x = 'foo';
const y = 'bar';

require('./sub.js');
```

And within `sub.js` you have the following:

```js
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

The console logs will fail because `x` and `y` are undefined. You'd have to modify the `index.js` file as such:

```js
global.x = 'foo';
global.y = 'bar';

require('./sub.js');
```

And with this modification, the `x` and `y` variables are now accessible from any module or file. Another way to change the index would be:

```js
const x = 'foo';
const y = 'bar';

global.x = x;
global.y = y;

require('./sub.js');
```

And in this instance, we're adding pre-existing variables to global instead of editing the lines where they're defined. That way, you can just slap something like this onto the end of your code for whatever variables you need in global.